# how to redirect www to non www nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I'm trying to redirect the www petitions to non-www domain, I tried the recommendation that everybody says but is not working for me, this is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site.com;
    return 301 $scheme://site.com$request_uri;
}
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name _;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/site.com/site;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name site.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com/site.>
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com/myserver.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This config works for me:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ http://example.com/ permanent;

  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sslcert/server/server.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sslcert/server/server.key;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ https://example.com/ permanent;             
}
```

I have added the `http` protocol along with the nginx configuration which I haven't used in my own server. However, this configuration should work for your case.